# How do I add a space after x amount of digits?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

How do I add a space after a certain amount of numbers?

If i have the number `02920555555` and wanted to add a space after the fifth number only, how would I go about that? Could I do this with a `gsub` and a regular expression? I would like to put it in a helper:

```
def area_code(tel)
  tel.gsub()
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `'\& '` as replacement string. (`\&` represents the matched string)

```
'02920555555'.gsub(/\d{4}/, '\& ')
# => "0292 0555 555"
```

**UPDATE**

to add a space after the 5th number only, use `sub` instead of `gsub`:

```
'02920555555'.sub(/\d{5}/, '\& ')
# => "02920 555555"
```

or using `gsub` with the pattern `^...` (matches only at the beginning of the input string):

```
'02920555555'.gsub(/^\d{5}/, '\& ')
# => "02920 555555"
```

Comment: sorry i may have worded my question incorrectly, i only want a space after the 5th digit only...many thanks for your help though. Would you be able to edit answer?

Comment: @Richlewis, I updated the answer according to the question change.

Answer (score 4):

Just use the [`insert`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-insert) method:

```
'02920555555'.insert(5, ' ')
# => "02920 555555"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't feel comfortable with `regex` then you can use the `insert` method:

```
'123456789'.insert(5, ' ')
```

The first parameter for the `insert` method is the position, (the index at which you want to insert) and second parameter is for the character that you want to insert.

So, our code is saying take number `123456789` and insert `space` at index `5`.

#### output:

```
"12345 6789"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'0292055555'.gsub(/(\d{5})(\d*)/, "\\1 \\2")
# => 02920 55555
```

Comment: Explain why this is useful and why it's the preferred way. An answer without an explanation is handing them a fish. Instead, teach them how to fish.